# React router 6.9.0 - How to render an array of routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem rendering some routes in React-Router version 6.9.0.

I'm rendering a `FormEditor` component like this, and it works to render the `FormEditor`

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="ui/forms/new/*"
        replace={true}
        element={
          <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <FormEditor />
          </I18nProvider>
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="ui/forms/:id/*"
        element={
          <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <FormEditor />
          </I18nProvider>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

But inside `FormEditor` I want to dynamically render some children like this:

```
import { routes } from './routes';

return (
  <HeaderLessLayout>
    <Routes>
      {formData && routes.map((r, key) => (
        <Route key={key} exact={r.exact} path={r.path} lazy={r.main} />
      ))}
    </Routes>
  </HeaderLessLayout>
)
```

And I have my routes.js file like this:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: "ui/forms/new",
    main: () => import('./FormLayoutEditor'),
    permission: 'menu_admin',
    exact: true
  },
  {
    path: "ui/forms/:id",
    main: () => import('./FormLayoutEditor'),
    permission: 'menu_admin',
    exact: true
  },
  {
    path: "ui/forms/:id/widget/:key",
    main: () => import('./FormWrapperEditor'),
    permission: 'menu_admin',
    exact: true
  }
];
```

But the children within `FormEditor` are not rendered. It seems like it's not matching any route inside the `FormEditor`. How is the correct approach to do this?

I did something similar with React-Router 5.1.2 and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two parent routes `"ui/forms/new"` and `"ui/forms/:id"`, and each is rendering a set of descendent routes `"ui/forms/new"`, `"ui/forms/:id"`, and `"ui/forms/:id/widget/:key"`. Descendent routes are built ***relative*** to their parent routes and will result in completes paths such as `"ui/forms/new/ui/forms/:id/widget/:key"`.

I suspect you meant to not include the `"/ui/forms"` path segments twice. Render only a single `"ui/forms/*"` parent route and update the `routes` array to specify paths *relative* to the parent path.

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="ui/forms/*"
        element={
          <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <FormEditor />
          </I18nProvider>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

```
import { routes } from './routes';

...

  return (
    <HeaderLessLayout>
      <Routes>
        {formData && routes.map((r) => (
          <Route key={r.path} path={r.path} lazy={r.main} />
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </HeaderLessLayout>
  );
```

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: "new",
    main: () => import('./FormLayoutEditor'),
    permission: 'menu_admin',
  },
  {
    path: ":id",
    main: () => import('./FormLayoutEditor'),
    permission: 'menu_admin',
  },
  {
    path: ":id/widget/:key",
    main: () => import('./FormWrapperEditor'),
    permission: 'menu_admin',
  }
];
```